# What is the meaning of に対して in this sentence ？

Tags: grammar, translation

> 一年生が三年生**に対して**──それも部のエースに向かって『雪乃さん』などと呼びかけてしまったのだ。無礼だと注意されても仕方がないだろう。

What does に対して refers to here？

Comment: So I guess that was considered 無礼 because 雪乃 is her first name?

Answer (score 4):

に対して and に向かって are being used in similar ways here to mean "in regards to" and "towards" respectively, to indicate who is being 呼びかけた'd.

Separately,

> 一年生が三年生に対して『雪乃さん』などと呼びかけてしまったのだ。

means

> "A first year (accidentally) addressed a third year as Yukinoさん (among other things)."

and

> 一年生が…部のエースに向かって『雪乃さん』などと呼びかけてしまったのだ。

means

> "A first year (accidentally) addressed a the club ace as Yukinoさん (among other things)."

それも is a conjunction used to mean "additionally" or "plus".
The "──" here is used to indicate the speaker has paused, which due to the それも following it, is most likely because they've just thought of adding the "ace" bit.

So in total, I would translate:

> 一年生が三年生に対して──それも部のエースに向かって『雪乃さん』などと呼びかけてしまったのだ。

as:

> "A first year (accidentally) addressed a third year - the club ace at that - as Yukinoさん (among other things)."